# Im attempting to create a search page for users to search other users throughout the database, but app keeps crashing

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When i press the button to get to my search page the app crashes and returns 
"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
I'm still new to coding and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
 @IBOutlet weak var SearchTable: UITableView!

    var userArray = [NSDictionary?]()
    var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()

    var dataRef = Database.database().reference()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        dataRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            self.userArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)

            self.SearchTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.userArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        return self.userArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchCell", for: indexPath)

        let user : NSDictionary?

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            user = self.userArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = user?["username"] as? String



        return cell
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

    }

    func filterContent(searchText:String)
    {
        self.filteredUsers = self.userArray.filter{ user in

            let Uname = user!["username"] as? String

            return(Uname?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!

        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }



}
```

I'm expecting for the page to open and i have the ability to search with the search bar. the error message i receive is 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: In the console, there should be a message with the exception that you received. There should also be a backtrace showing the specific line of code that crashed. Use this information to track down the cause of the exception.

Comment: I'm stil learning so i don't fully understand what you mean, would this be it?*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-vhH-By-pea" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Firebase. From the comment you have written under your question, you pasted this console message `instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-vhH-By-pea" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'`. I believe you have hooked up a `UIViewController` screen from the Storyboard with a `UITableViewController` class. This is wrong, you need to change your class to be a subclass of `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`. Then, set the `SearchTableView`'s delegate and dataSource to it.

So, your class should be:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ... {
```

Then set the TableView's delegate and dataSource to `self` in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    SearchTableView.dataSource = self
    SearchTableView.delegate = self
    // ...
}
```

By the way, if your Controller only have a `UITableView` in it and nothing else, then, you may want to consider using a `UITableViewController` instead of a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. `UITableViewController` is esseentially a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` being the main view on it, so no need to redo all the work :)

Comment: yo man thank you so much! i been frusterated for a few days now and this fixed it. You were right i changed it to a tableview THANK YOU!!! thank you, thank you!

Comment: @Peakz If his/her answer helped you, you should accept it.